# Error when trying to deploy SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

I am trying to deploy my 2012 SSIS project to the Integration Services catalog on the SSIS server (also 2012).  I am getting the error below.  I checked that there is plenty of space in SSISDB and msdb databases as well as on the disk.  Any ideas what might be causing this?

[image]

Comment: What does the ssisdb.catalog.operation_messages have to say about the deployment operation? What if you try a different deployment mechanism, do you get any more detailed error messages? This is a [tsql](https://gist.github.com/billinkc/582cd7bbf2b500bcbed5) deployment

Comment: Thank you for the script!  I tried it and got a similar error.  It did have a name of the offending stored procedure:
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Procedure prepare_deploy, Line 298
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

The catalog.operation_messages is completely empty.

Comment: I even tried to step through the involved MS procedures, which get called by "deploy_project", however the debugging functionality in SSMS is still very flaky and it crashed on me every time I tried :(  It seems that "prepare_deploy" stored procedure performs a lot of security checks and this is where things break.

Comment: I tracked down the issue to a series of statements in "internal.prepare_deploy" stored procedure, which deal with various aspects of security keys.  The procedure builds a dynamic sql string similar to this: CREATE CERTIFICATE MS_Cert_Proj_20 WITH SUBJECT = 'ISServerCertificate' and then tries to run it via sp_executesql.  That's when it crashes.  I copied the string and ran it manually in a different window without issues.  I tried to "cheat" by commenting out these lines and executing them myself, but this gets very complicated due to various internal calls as well as  procedure scope.

Comment: Here are examples of these lines: `SET @sqlString = 'CREATE CERTIFICATE ' + @certificate_name + ' WITH SUBJECT = ''ISServerCertificate'''
            
            IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[certificates] WHERE [name] = @certificate_name)
                 EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlString 
            
            SET @sqlString = 'CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY ' + @key_name +' WITH ALGORITHM = ' 
                                + @encryption_algorithm + ' ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ' + @certificate_name`

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem, and was able to resolve it by disabling a DDL trigger on the SSISDB database for `DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS`.  The trigger was trying to write info into another Database.